# ParrotOS 2019: How to change trackpad to fit a lefty?

Tags: touchpad, mate-desktop, parrotsec, mate-panel

I am lefty here.

How do you change the mouse usage in Parrot Linux 2019 to be left-handed?
Specifically the trackpad... I have changed the 'Mouse Orientation' to 'left-handed'.

But the trackpad is still righty ???

I am using Parrot either 4.6 or 4.7, not so sure. What I am sure, that it is a Mate Desktop, I think. I just installed it like about month ago, not sure which.. Typed `uname` spits nothing bout the version.

Not sure what to do anymore. Still noob here..

Comment: Please add the output of `dmesg | grep -i trackpad` and `grep -i trackpad /var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see whether we find some info on how your trackpad is addressed by the system.

Comment: Huh.. they all outputted nothing dude. Both `dmesg | grep -i trackpad` and `grep -i trackpad /var/log/Xorg.0.log` outputed nothing. They all returned new `$` prompt. Unfortunately...

Comment: Oops, I don't have a machine with a trackpad available right now so maybe it is the wrong string I searched for. Please look in the X log file for the input device that represents your trackpad. Perhaps it lists the manufacturer, and that could be grep'ed then?

Comment: Hmm.. Ok @Ned64, I'll try to look into it when I hv the time. As I know there are plenty of logs in linux right in /var/logs iirc (as I am still usin Win7 rite now)... which one should I look into man?? Some of them are thousands of lines per boot.. it'll be like searching for a lost key in the forest man...

Comment: You can make it easy for yourself and stick to the X log file I have already referenced. Check there for input devices and copy everything about your trackpad into your question with nice code formatting.